# Can I render HTML in django without sending a response?

Tags: django, xlwt

I want to create a generic "html table to excel file" view that can be used by several other views displaying query results in HTML tables. I thought I can add a parameter to every query view that makes it render the HTML *without sending a response*, but using it instead to feed a helper function that will parse it and convert the table rows and columns to Excel content by using the **xlwt** library.

Can I do this "render without response" in django?

Comment: Alternatively, could I make the generic view receive the initial request and call the "regular" view to obtain the response object and get the HTML from it?

Comment: Yes, you can wrap views if you like (i.e. call one view from within another view, do something with the output and then return a response)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
rendered = render_to_string('my_template.html', { 'foo': 'bar' })
```

[here are the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut)